# Login activity in android

Tags: android, authentication, android-activity

I'm trying to create a login page in android and I've checked the link below for [an example](http://vimaltuts.com/training/android-tutorial-for-beginners)

but unfortunately when I press the login button i will receive a unexpected exception and my application will stop!

[here I've pasted my logcat](http://pastebin.com/EsYA5nGt)

!would you please help me what should I do or guide me through creating a simple login page which checks the validity of password?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you narrow down the logcat to just the relevant bits, and post it here, please?

Comment: Please paste the code in your question, and reduce the logcat to just the important bits (i.e. what's "red" +/- 5 lines)

Comment: Thanks a lot,The answer below has solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the log says

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.example.loginsystemv1/com.example.loginsystemv1.WelcomePage};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

The activity that you start on button click has not been declared in Manifest file

Comment: Thanks a lot,I've added the activities in my manifest!and I worked.